# Can't get correct values from each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object (called `allUserInfo` that's like this:

```
Object
{
available_client_ids: Array[2]
0: "demo"
1: "4532t78"
available_client_names: Array[2]
0: "Demo"
1: "Bobs Bakery"
email: "jmr@example.com
}
```

I need to get the `available_client_ids` and `available_client_names`, but keep coming back with undefined or worse. I'm trying something like this:

```
$.each(allUserInfo, function(index, value) {
$('.clients_available3').append("<option>" + index.available_client_names + "</option>");
   });
```

This give me too many undefined things appended to the select (`clients_available3`). It likely needs to be something like:

```
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(index, value) {
$('.clients_available3').append("<option>" + index.available_client_names + "</option>");
   });
```

but that doesn't work either.

**EDIT**

If I do this,

```
   $.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(index, value) {
                $('.clients_available3').append("<option>" + value + " </option>");
});
```

This works and gives me the client names, but I don't have a way to get the ids. I was hoping I could do something like this so I could get them both, but this doesn't work:

```
 $.each(allUserInfo, function(index, value) {
                $('.clients_available3').append("<option value="+available_client_ids+">" + available_client_names.value + " </option>");
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(index)` and see if the object is returning everything you expect.

Comment: why `index.available...` and not `value.available...`? it's the `value` that has this property, not the `index`...

Comment: @JamesThorpe You're right. Just figured that out. See my edit for the additional challenge I have.

Comment: @Steve It's all there as I want, but check out my edit for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native JavaScript for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<allUserInfo.available_client_names.length){
    var name = allUserInfo.available_client_names[i];
    var id = allUserInfo.available_client_ids[i];
    $('.clients_available3').append("<option value='"+id+"'>" + name + "</option>");
}
```

Or update your original code to the following:

```
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(index, value) {
   $('.clients_available3').append("<option value='"+allUserInfo.available_client_ids[index]+"'>" + available_client_names[index] + "</option>");
   });
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I needed to make one little change to your second script though. `available_client_names[index]` to `allUserInfo.available_client_names[index]`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong things inside the each() loop...

```
function(index, value) { }
```

the `index` value is the **KEY** that you're currently iterating on in the object. In your case, it'll be "available_clients_ids", "available_client_names", and "email".

The `value` parameter will be the values of those keys, e.g. the array that contains "demo" and "4532t78"

Since you've got what is essentially a nested array (an object with multiple attributes, and each attribute contains an array), you'd need something more like this:

```
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(i, val) {
   ...
});
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_ids, function(i, val) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Got it. See my edit for what I really need, which is to get the values for ids and names back together, so I can tie them back together. Based on what the user selects (from possible names), I want to get the name AND the ID. In my edit, I hacked a way to do this by using `value`, which would work if I could get the right values.

Comment: assuming the index keys in those two arrays will always have 1:1 position conrrespondence, then use a single `$.each()`, and use the `i` index you get from the loop to look up the corresponding value in the other array, e.g. `.each(yourObj.array1, function (i) { alert(yourObj.otherarray[i]); }`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use .each with its two parameter function calling.
I mean:

```
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(index, value) {
   $('.clients_available3').append("<option>" + available_client_names[index] + "</option>");
   });
```

or you can use directly the value being iterated on, like:

```
$.each(allUserInfo.available_client_names, function(index, value) {
$('.clients_available3').append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
   });
```